# How focused JUnit tests in BDD way should be

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, bdd

I'm test-driving some code  for practice and spotted strange situation.

There is a ChannelRegistry that contains all communication channels references, and PrimaryConsumer who needs to attach itself to one of those channels choosen in runtime when initialize() called.
So I've done my first test as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PrimaryConsumerTest {

    private @Mock ChannelsRegistry communicationRegistry;
    private PrimaryConsumer consumer;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        consumer = new PrimaryConsumer(communicationRegistry);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAttachToChannel() throws Exception {
        consumer.initialize();
        verify(communicationRegistry).attachToChannel("channel", consumer);
    }
}
```

I'm checking if attaching method is called. To get it green I put impl like that:

```
public void initialize() {
    communicationRegistry.attachToChannel("channel", this);
}
```

Now next test: get channel id by name and attach to this specific channel. I want my test to describe class' behavior instead of its internals so I don't want my test to be "shouldGetSpecificChannel". Instead I check if it can attach to channel selected in runtime:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldAttachToSpecificChannel() throws Exception {
        String channelName = "channel";
        when(communicationRegistry.getChannel("channel_name")).thenReturn(channelName);
        consumer.initialize();
        verify(communicationRegistry).attachToChannel(channelName, consumer);
    }
```

This test passes immediately, but implementation is screwed ("channel" hardcoded).

2 questions here:

- is it ok to have 2 tests for such behavior? Maybe I should stub getting channel immediately in first test? If so, how does it map to testing single thing in single test?
- how to cope with such situation: tests green, impl "hardcoded"? Should I write another test with different channel's name? If so, should I remove it after correcting impl (as it gets useless?)

**UPDATE:**
Just some clarifications.
I've hardcoded "channel" here

```
public void initialize() {
    communicationRegistry.attachToChannel("channel", this);
}
```

just to make first test pass quickly. But then, when running second test it passes immediately. I don't verify if stubbed method was called as I think stubs should not be verified explicitly. 
Is this what you Rodney mean saying test are redundant? If yes shoud I make stub at the very beginning in the first test?

Answer (score 1):

1. More tests is usually preferred to too few, so two tests is fine. A better question is whether the two tests are redundant: is there any situation or combination of inputs that would make one of the tests fail, but not the other?   Then the two tests are both needed.  If they always fail or succeed together, then you probably need only one of them.
2. When would you need a different value for `channelName`?  It sounds like this is a configuration setting that is irrelevant to these particular tests.   That's fine, perhaps you would test that configuration at a higher level, in your integration tests.   A bigger concern I would have is why it's hard-coded in the first place: it should be injected into your class (probably via the constructor).  Then you can test different channel names -- or not.  Either way, you *don't* want to be changing your code just for testing if it means changing it back when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question to clarify some points from your post. Please see the version updated above.

Answer (score 1):

Basically ditto Rodney for the question of multiple tests. I would suggest, based on your update, one or two things.

First off, you have used the same data for both tests. In the Kent Beck book on TDD he mentions the use of "Triangulation". If you used different reference data in the second case then your code would not have passed without any additional work on your part.

On the other hand, he also mentions removing all duplication, and duplication includes duplication between the code and the tests. In this scenario you could have left both of your tests as is, and refactored out the duplication between the string `"channel"` in the code and the same in the test by replacing the literal in your class under test with the call to your `communicationRegistry.getChannel()`. After this refactoring you now have the string literal in one and only one place: The test.

Two different approaches, same result. Which one you use comes down to personal preference. In this scenario I would have taken the second approach, but that's just me.

Reminder to check out Rodney's answer to the question of multiple tests or not. I'm guessing you could delete the first one.

Thanks!

Brandon